# Copy records from one table to another sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables. I want to copy data from table one with 1 column (datestamp) in table 2 with 6 columns (id,name,rid,action,timestamp,datestamp).
Now all columns (records) in table 2 are filled except datestamp column, that is filled with 'null'. so i want to copy datestamp from table 1 to table 2 where datestamp in table 2 is null
Plz help.

Comment: If you have nothing to link records in table 1 with table 2, how do you know which datestamp goes with which record?

Comment: i want to copy datestamp column values from table 1 to table 2 where datestamp in table 2 is null

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key on both your tables:

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.[datestamp] = T1.[datestamp]
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN Table1 T1
    ON T2.id = T1.id
WHERE T2.[datestamp] IS NULL
```